# How can I get the double braces working for my angularjs repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

For some reason this bit of code isn't working. To clarify, I'll get the correct number of spaces where info should be printed out. I'll see that customers has an array with the amount of objects it's supposed to have. I just won't see any info that should come from the braces. When I try to print just customer, I get the entire JSON object and its info. However, when I use customer.Name (or any attributes), I get blank space. I checked several times on the network side to make sure, but all of the attributes are the exact way I have them below.

```
tr ng-repeat="customer in customers| orderBy:predicate:reverse track by $index" ng-click="showMore($index)" >
    <td>{{customer}} {{customer.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{customer.Email}}</td>
    <td id="{{$index}}" ng-model="moreInfo" ng-hide="true">
    Username: {{customer.Username}} || Last Modified: {{customer.LastModifiedDate}}
  </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Can you throw this in a plunkr for us to look at?

Answer (score 0):

The objects should look like this after the JSON is parsed

```
$scope.customers = [
  {
  Name : "brian",
  Email: "email",
  Username: "username"
  },
  {
  Name : "brian2",
  Email: "email2",
  Username: "username2"
  },
];
```